# Entire div clickable with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dropzone.js, dropzone

I'm using `dropzone.js` for Ajax uploading of images. The problem is that I have the following div containers

```
<div id="images-container" class="ui-sortable dz-clickable">
  <div id="file-image">
    <p><b>Add images</b></p>
    <small>Click or drag&drop here</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

And `dropzone.js` is initialised as follows:

```
$("#file-image").dropzone();
```

My css is looking like this:

```
#file-image {
  border: 1px solid rgb(187, 187, 187);
  background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the text (Add images or Click or drag & drop.) the plugin cannot be activated. How can I make the entire `#file-image` div clickable?

Comment: Try with a <button> Tag instead of a div.

Comment: Check this question if u haven't already  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181487/how-to-make-only-the-dropzone-js-previews-div-clickable-and-not-the-whole-form

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306158/prevent-html-text-to-distort-clickable-overlay/50306191#50306191

Comment: @patelarpan it works.

#file-image p, #file-image small{
    pointer-events: none;
}

Comment: Check this sample, you need a form instead of div: https://codepen.io/blackjacques/pen/jyxNqL

Comment: Then upvote @Rostislav :)

Comment: Already done :)

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your div to a form and added an action and it seems to be working fine.

HTML

```
<div id="images-container" class="ui-sortable dz-clickable">
  <form action="/action" id="file-image" class="dropzone">
    <p><b>Add images</b></p>
  </form>
</div>
```

This an extract from the official website - ["Dropzone will find all form elements with the class dropzone, automatically attach itself to it, and upload files dropped into it to the specified action attribute."](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#installation)

So I think you need to use the action attribute to get it to work.

Codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGKBgY

Comment: I already have <form> so I want to stick to it. I don't need another one.